# Can I post to Facebook with my own text from Unity on behalf of the user?

Tags: unity, facebook

I'm using Facebook SDK for Unity 6.0 with FB.Feed.

I'm trying to post a link to the user's feed, text and link on his behalf.

So far I've managed to publish only a link and its details, the part where the user can write the post is left empty for him to fill.

Comment: Unity 6.0? Didn't they just release 5.0?

Answer (score 1):

```
if (FB.IsLoggedIn)
    {
            FB.Feed(
            linkCaption: "YourGame",
            picture: "http://YourImageLink.png",
            linkName: "YourGameMessage!",
            link: "http://apps.facebook.com/" + FB.AppId + "/?challenge_brag" + (FB.IsLoggedIn ? FB.UserId : "guest")
            );
    }
```

Comment: `FB.IsLoggedIn ? FB.UserId : "guest"` is redundant considering that `FB.IsLoggedIn` is the condition for the whole block.

Comment: FB.IsLoggedIn should still work with previous fb sdk versions 6 or below. With the latest fb sdk and the new changes we can now use FB.ShareLink() or FB.FeedShare()